# Silent installation of Visual Studio 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I try to install Visual Studio 2013 Express silently. Sadly, the following code doesn't work as it should:

wdexpress_full.exe /passive /noweb /norestart

It still installs from web, and after that it throws out Error 3010 (Reboot required).
I heard about SQL Server or .NET 4.5 causing the reboot, and that I should install them separately before the Installation.
To exclude them from VS13, I tried to use /adminfile, but it seems this parameter doesn't work for the Express-Version

So I tried installing every single .msi-File. Most times I need parameters like VSEXTUI=1 or USING_EXUIH=1 for them to work without being called by the .exe, but then they install without problems.
But at the End, Visual Studio won't start. It shows me the following error:

"Die Anwendung konnte nicht gestartet werden, da die Side-by-Side-Konfiguration ungültig ist. Weitere Informationen erhalten Sie im Anwendungsereignisprotokoll. Weitere Details können auch mit dem Befehlszeilentool sxstrace.exe angezeigt werden"

Sadly I cannot find what's the exact English error text, but it says, that the application cannot be started because the Side-by-Side-Configuration is invalid, and I can get further information through sxstrace.exe.
sxstrace gives me the following file: http://www.file-upload.net/download-8934591/sxstrace.txt.html

Answer (score 4):

For people having issues with the MSI files, for example

```
vc_compilerCore86.msi
```

I was getting this error

```
To install this product, please run Setup.exe.
```

I [found a fix](http://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/tools/depot_tools/+/1395e48/win_toolchain/toolchain2013.py#161) for it. You need to run it as *Administrative install*

```
msiexec -a vc_compilerCore86.msi
```

Side note, Visual Studio Express comes in 2 versions

[Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40748) 408 MB

[Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop](http://microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787) 790 MB

Comment: I found that also `ADDEPLOY=1` can be used to circumvent the check (I used that to install just a minimal C++ build environment without the other 4.5+ GB of useless stuff).